# join two collections with mongoose and want to include the quantity field in the result

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, nosql-aggregation

**My Collections:**

[users collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IArMO.png)

[entities collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZcvo.png)

**My Code:**

```
const user = await User.aggregate().lookup({
      from: 'entities',
      localField: 'cartId.entityId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'cartId.entityId',
    });
```

**Result:**

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWZst.png)

**My Problem:** I want quantity exist in result but it's not. What I can do?